# how can i change the parent iframe size from inside with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

we have a ReactJs code that will run as an iframe in a website
the problem is that we have lots of clients that set iframe height 700px as default and we can not tell all of them to change it and we don't have access to the iframes.
and this will make our project scrollable.
we want to make it full size without scroll from inside.

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="700" src="url" frameborder="0" id="myIframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: you cannot set dimensions of iframe. it is set by all the clients

Comment: @ShlokJain thanks, But is there any way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should change width and height's unit from **%** to **viewport** that will be compatible with all devices, for eg: set width to `100vw`, this sets the iframe's width to cover the complete viewport width so width will be dynamic same goes for height set it to `100vh`
also to add styling remove width and height attribute of that iframe and add inline styling for the same as,

```
<iframe style="width: 100vw; height:100vh" src="url" frameborder="0" id="myIframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: it isn't what i want but tnx for replying. otherwise there is no way you can access to the outer of iframe that build in the client site. so there should be a script beside of the iframe to handle this problem. (make a connection bridge between inner iframe and outer one)